# How can I convert a Map<String, dynamic> to a Map<String,List<int>>?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to get from a firebase document an object which originally was a `Map<String,List<int>>` and now in the document is `Map<String, dynamic>`. But when I use .from():

`Map<String,List<int>> schedule = Map<String,List<int>>.from(snapshot.data['schedule'])`

`Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, List<dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, List<int>>'`

Comment: how did you declared schedule variable ?

Comment: as a Map<String,List<int>>

Comment: please provide your initialization and document model !

Answer (score 0):

```dart
Map<String, List<int>> schedule = snapshot.data['schedule'].map(
    (k, v) => MapEntry(
      k,
      (v as List<dynamic>).cast<int>(),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a few things.

First, you can lazily cast each value as it's extracted:

```dart
Map<String, List<int>> schedule = 
    (snapshot.data['schedule'] as Map<String, dynamic>).cast<String, List<int>();
```

The `cast` operation wraps the original map and does a type check on each access.

Or you can create a new map:

```dart
var schedule = <String, List<int>>{... snapshot.data['schedule']};
```

This creates a new `Map<String, List<int>>` with the same keys and values as the schedule, and checks the type when the map is created.